# MacRuby 0.10 HotCocoa unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, llvm, x86-64, macruby, hotcocoa

I've installed MacRuby (via rvm):

```
$ ruby -v
MacRuby 0.10 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin10.0, x86_64]
```

And LLVM (via homebrew):

```
$ llvmc --version
Low Level Virtual Machine (http://llvm.org/):
llvm version 2.9
Optimized build.
Built Jun  3 2011 (10:06:35).
Host: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Host CPU: corei7

Registered Targets:
(none)
```

When I run rake, I get an error:

```
$ rake
(in /Users/briankierstead/dev/kci/macruby/hourz)
ld: warning: in /Library/Frameworks//MacRuby.framework/MacRuby, file was built for
 unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_macruby_main", referenced from:
  _main in ccvGpB6J.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/qm/qm1gYJL6Fa4uPhnq239pak+++TI/-Tmp-//ccS18qN4.out (No such file or directory)
```

I *don't* want to run xcode4, which allows you specify x86_64 as the output.

How can I resolve this issue?  It looks like somewhere in the chain, 32-bit is being specified.  I've tried compiling with flags, and running rake as:

```
env UNIVERSAL=1 UNIVERSAL_ARCH="x86_64" ENABLE_OPTIMIZED=1
```

and

```
RC_ARCHS=x86_64 rake
```

But none of these makes a difference.  I get the same error.

I'm on Snow Leopard - 10.6.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using hotcocoa from this [repo](https://github.com/ferrous26/hotcocoa) solves the problem.  The published version is outdated and ignores architecture.

Not ideal, but at least it works until the published version catches up.

Thanks goes to @watson1978

This worked, but gave rise to another error: LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810

I had to install [BridgeSupport](http://www.macruby.org/files/) and then everything worked fine.